# .Net Maui .exe wont run on Windows server

Tags: .net-core, windows-server, maui, windows-app-sdk

I have built a .net maui application with blazor using the following command:

`dotnet publish -f net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release -p:WindowsPackageType=None /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true --self-contained true /p:DebugType=None /p:EnableCompressionInSingleFile=true`

The application runs fine on my development machine (Windows 10)

It also runs fine on another machine i tested after installing Windows app sdk 1.1 from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/downloads

However, on a Windows server 2019 machine i am unable to install Windows app sdk 1.1 (it crashes after a few console lines), and the .net maui application will not open.

Comment: Crashes with what error? Did you check the Event log?

Answer (score 2):

This scenario is known as unpackaged publishing and is not supported yet. This issue tracks the progress and adds some instructions that you might try to make it work today: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3166